# SQL: Deduce Effective Pricing from overlapping Dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have pricing record with overlapping dates. On few dates there are more than one overlapping prices. Please follow the example below:

Example on 2022/02/15 there are 2 prices 10 and 8 .

| article | price | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 2022/02/02 | 2049/12/31 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022/02/14 | 2022/09/14 |
| 123 | 5 | 2022/03/14 | 2022/04/06 |
| 123 | 4 | 2022/04/11 | 2022/04/27 |

I want to apply the effective price for date ranges like below and avoid conflicting prices in the output.

| article | price | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 2022/02/02 | 2022/02/13 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022/02/14 | 2022/03/13 |
| 123 | 5 | 2022/03/14 | 2022/04/06 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022/04/07 | 2022/04/10 |
| 123 | 4 | 2022/04/11 | 2022/04/27 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022/04/28 | 2022/09/14 |
| 123 | 10 | 2022/09/15 | 2049/12/31 |

I can think of window functions to adjust the end dates and prices, but I cannot wrap my head around the problem completely to get the complete solution. Any suggestion/solution is appreciated.

Database: Snowflake

Thank you

Comment: What's the logic for resolving conflicting price. Why was 8 applied to date range 04/07 -04/10? Why not 10?

Comment: @PhilCoulson Think of it as a sequence of overrides. The value starts as NULL (from the dawn of time), then is overridden to 10 (from 2nd Feb 2022), then is overridden to 8, then is overridden to 5. When that third override expires, it reverts back to 8, because that was the most recent override that is still in effect.

Comment: @SomuSinhhaa Does your data ever have partial overlaps? Such as Row1=1st-5th and Row2=3rd-7th?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the logic of new starting price window wins for overlaps.

### Discreate Date version:

```
with data(article,price,startdate,enddate) as (
    select * FROM VALUES
        (123, 10, '2022-02-02'::date, '2049-12-31'::date),
        (123, 8,  '2022-02-14'::date, '2022-09-14'::date),
        (123, 5,  '2022-03-14'::date, '2022-04-06'::date),
        (123, 4,  '2022-04-11'::date, '2022-04-27'::date)
), dis_times as (
    select article,
        date as startdate,
        lead(date) over(partition by article order by date)-1 as enddate
    from (
        select distinct article, startdate as date from data
        union
        select distinct article, enddate+1 as date from data
    )
    qualify enddate is not null
)
select 
    d1.article, 
    d1.price, 
    d2.startdate,
    d2.enddate
from data as d1
join dis_times as d2
    on d1.article = d2.article 
        and d2.startdate between d1.startdate and d1.enddate qualify row_number() over (partition by d1.article, s_startdate order by d1.startdate desc) = 1
order by 1,3;
```

gives:

| ARTICLE | PRICE | S_STARTDATE | S_ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-13 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022-02-14 | 2022-03-13 |
| 123 | 5 | 2022-03-14 | 2022-04-06 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022-04-07 | 2022-04-10 |
| 123 | 4 | 2022-04-11 | 2022-04-27 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022-04-28 | 2022-09-14 |
| 123 | 10 | 2022-09-15 | 2049-12-31 |

### Continuous Timestamp version:

```
with data(article,price,startdate,enddate) as (
    select * FROM VALUES
        (123, 10, '2022-02-02'::date, '2049-12-31'::date),
        (123, 8,  '2022-02-14'::date, '2022-09-14'::date),
        (123, 5,  '2022-03-14'::date, '2022-04-06'::date),
        (123, 4,  '2022-04-11'::date, '2022-04-27'::date)
), dis_times as (
    select article,
        date as startdate,
        lead(date) over(partition by article order by date) as enddate
    from (
        select distinct article, startdate as date from data
        union
        select distinct article, enddate as date from data
    )
    qualify enddate is not null
)
select 
    d1.article, 
    d1.price, 
    d2.startdate,
    d2.enddate
from data as d1
join dis_times as d2
    on d1.article = d2.article 
        and d2.startdate >= d1.startdate and d2.startdate < d1.enddate
qualify row_number() over (partition by d1.article, s_startdate order by d1.startdate desc) = 1
order by 1,3;
```

which gives:

| ARTICLE | PRICE | S_STARTDATE | S_ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 10 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-14 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022-02-14 | 2022-03-14 |
| 123 | 5 | 2022-03-14 | 2022-04-06 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022-04-06 | 2022-04-11 |
| 123 | 4 | 2022-04-11 | 2022-04-27 |
| 123 | 8 | 2022-04-27 | 2022-09-14 |
| 123 | 10 | 2022-09-14 | 2049-12-31 |

Thanks to MatBailie for the tighter join suggestion.

```
join dis_times as d2
    on d1.article = d2.article 
        and d2.startdate between d1.startdate and d1.enddate
```

the continuous range I would normally do in this for

```
and d2.startdate between d1.startdate and d1.enddate and d2.startdate < d1.enddate
```

instead of this form

```
and d2.startdate >= d1.startdate and d2.startdate < d1.enddate
```

because I in experience it performed better. always test your complexities.

Comment: You can simplify the final join. First, you don't need a left join, you already know one set of dates is derived from the other, which means that the outer join case should never happen. Second, you only actually need to find rows in dis_times where the ***start*** is within the data table's window; again, because you know that the ranges in dis_dates are made from the ranges in the data (if the data is 1-7, 3-5, then you ***know*** you make ranges 1-3, 3-5, 5-7 but ***never*** make 3-7 or any other range that partially overlaps a source range).

Comment: true the left join was a hang over from my original self join and want to handle now overlapping rows. you second point is not clicking for me.. AH the `dis_time` is always sub sets, and never larger, as it's ... yes, another hang over from the original self join.

Comment: Now you can always select the d2 start and end dates too. Because they're always a subset of d1. No need for least or greatest.

Comment: Oh, and your continuous answer's join needs >= AND <, rather than BETWEEN.

Comment: Great Thanks a ton for your help SimeonPilgrim and @MatBailie

Comment: @SomuSinhhaa - For fun I played with a few alternatives for you, they can be ported to snowflake, but the demos are in oracle...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=72ca45607696727018e5fc5bf6feb5c6

Comment: Thank you Team, for all the help. The solution works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I did was --I turned your price-per-date range data into a price-per-date lookup table.

```
create or replace temporary table price_date_lookup as
 
select distinct 
       article,
       dateadd('day',b.index-1,start_date) as dates,
       first_value(price) over (partition by article, dates order by end_date) as price
from my_table, 
     lateral split_to_table(repeat('.',datediff(day,start_date,end_date)), '.') b;
```

**Notes:**

- `first_value` handles overlaps by overriding prices based on their end dates.
- `lateral...` basically helps create a date column with all the days in the range

---

As soon as I created that table, I figured the rest could be approached like a `gaps and island` problem.

```
with cte1 as

(select *, case when lag(price) over (partition by article order by dates)=price then 0 else 1 end as price_start --flag start of a new price island
 from price_date_lookup),
 
cte2 as
 
(select *, sum(price_start) over (partition by article order by dates) as price_id --assign id to all the price islands
 from cte1)

 
select article, 
       price,
       min(dates) as start_date,
       max(dates) as end_date
from cte2
group by article,price,price_id;
```